# What is the correct client name for WeChat

Tags: python, windows, import, module, wechat

What to do if Python says "No module named 'wechat_client'"? If the client name for WeChat isn't correct, then what should be the correct name? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> from pywxclient.core import Session, SyncClient

>>> s1 = Session()

>>> c1 = SyncClient(s1)

>>> c1.get_authorize_url()  # Open the url in web browser

>>> c1.authorize()  # Continue authorize when returning False

>>> c1.login()

>>> c1.sync_check()

>>> msgs = c1.sync_message()  # Here are your wechat messages

>>> c1.flush_sync_key()
```

From [Official Repo](https://github.com/justdoit0823/pywxclient)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as I tried, it says "NameError: name 'Session' is not defined". So how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: `pip install pywxclient`